# Is there any changes on IMonitor interface provided from Microsoft.ML.AutoML Ver0.20.1 and Ver0.21.1?

Tags: winforms, automl

OS: Windows11 Pro 23H2 OS build 22631.3007
Tool: Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.8.5
Language: C#
Framework: .NET 8.0

Making a Windows form application with

- Microsoft.ML Version 3.0.1
- Microsoft.ML.AutoML Version 0.21.1

I'm having a problem with my application since it would not get any events like clicking button controls and any other things.  With Microsoft.ML.AutoML Version 0.20.1, it worked just fine.

I refered to ["How to use the ML.NET Automated ML(AutoML) API"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/how-to-use-the-automl-api) on Microsoft Learn.  It's for a console application so I modified for Windows form application.  Using IMonitor interface for monitoring how trials are doing.

```
var monitor = new AutoMLMonitor(pipeline, rtbLog, lblMax, mlContext, data, CSV_name);
experiment.SetMonitor(monitor);
cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
TrialResult experimentResults = await experiment.RunAsync(cts.Token);
```

Since Microsoft.ML.AutoML Version 0.20.1 works fine, I could use it.  However, I may loose the other benefits from newer version.

Comment: I've thrown the same question to GitHub and got my app to work with Microsoft.ML.AutoML Version 0.21.1.

[Link](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/6979)